# Программа должна разделять предложение на слова, и печатать их в столбик, но почему-то последнее слово не печатается. Сам питон ошибок не выдает

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот код:

```
str1 = input("Input your text please: ")
slovo = "" 
list1 = []

for iter1 in str1:
 if iter1 != " ":
  slovo += iter1
  print(iter1)
 else:
  list1.append(slovo)
  slovo = ""


for iter2 in range(0,len(list1)):
 print(list1[iter2])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот здесь вы добавляете слово в список результатов, только если встретили пробел, которым слово заканчивается:

```
if iter1 != " ":
    ...
else: # if iter1 == ' '
    list1.append(slovo)
```

Но в конце вводимой строки нет пробела. Поэтому последнее слово не добавляется в список, следовательно не печатается.

---

Всё это имеет смысл только как упражнение на алгоритмы. В Python есть готовые решения для того, чтобы:

- Разбить строку на подстроки (слова) по пробелам. Получится список.

  ```
  words = str1.split()
  ```
- Что-то сделать со всеми элементами списка.

  ```
  for word in words:
      print (word)
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Печатает введенные слова в столбик

```
data = input("Input your text please: ")
words = []

for w in data.split():
    words.append(w)
    print(w)
```

Comment: мне нужен ответ на мой вопрос: какая ошибка в коде, а не аналогичная программа

Comment: @Михаил у вас не код, а полнейшая ерунда написана

Comment: даже если этот код ерунда, мне не нужны альтернативы ему, я все четко изложил в вопросе

Comment: @Михаил в вашем вопросе не чего не понятно, что вы хотите, там просто описание проблемы, а про то в каком виде вы хотите видеть ответ нет ни слова

Comment: у меня есть неисправность в коде, а точнее не выводится последнее слово, вот я и не понимаю что в моем коде не так.

Comment: @Михаил, помимо того, чтобы разобраться что не так в вашем коде - есть смысл обратить внимание на альтернативные решения/подходы - это поможет вам быстрее и полнее  выучить предмет.

Comment: @MaxU вы правы, но я специально делаю более прямолинейными решениями, чтобы понять как работают те или иные методы